# Warum heißt es im Genitiv "Jesu" und "Christi"?

Tags: noun

Im Wörterbuch bin ich neulich auf den folgenden Ausdruck gestoßen:

> die Leidensgeschichte **Jesu** *oder* **Christi**

Mich interessiert, warum Jesu nicht Jesus oder Christ [~ Christus] (wie, zum Beispiel, im Englischen) gennant ist. Woher kommt der Unterschied? Haben wir dabei mit der Etymologie zu tun?

Comment: Eine Frage, die an sich nach "Latin" gehört.

Comment: Editing the title to contain the answer seems not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

In "die Leidensgeschichte Jesu" bzw. "die Leidensgeschichte Christi" steht Jesus bzw. Christus im Genitiv (wessen Leidensgeschichte?). Die Formen "Jesu" bzw. "Christi" dürften auf das Lateinische zurückgehen, immerhin war Latein viele Jahrhunderte die Sprache der Kirche und der Liturgie.

Answer (score 5):

*Christi* ist lateinisch (Genitiv der o-Deklination).

*Jesu* ist von lateinisch "Iesu", der latinisierten Form des (alt-)griechischen Genitivs *Jesou*.

Comment: This comment should be expanded into an answer.

Comment: Likewise: *Mariä Himmelfahrt*: *Mariae* is genitive of Latin Maria.